# Can't stop propagation of event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, stoppropagation

I'm a bit confused. I have list of what are names with a checkbox next to them. The list is constructed dynamically in after doing a post to the backend.

Problem is whenever I click on the checkbox it immediately gets unchecked. The reason I know this is that if an alert is inserted in the event, the checkbox is actually checked, until the alert is dismissed.

This is my code:

```
$("#NamesList").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
    CheckboxClicked();
    return false;
})
.on("click", "li", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    switch (e.target.nodeName) {
         case "A":
             GetPerson(e.target.href)
             break;
         case "LI":
              GetPerson($("a", e.target).attr("href"))
              break;
         default: return false;
     }

     return false;
});
```

Thing is, I have link in the listitem that I need to be able to follow. If the part for navigating to the link is taken out, the checkbox functionality works fine.

This is what a typical list of names look like:

```
<ul id="NamesList">
     <li id="1">
         <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
         <a href="/some/link/somewhere/1">John Smith</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is this `CheckboxClicked();` & `GetPerson()`supposed to do?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks, sorry about that, will edit it to look correct. I wast typing the question out and it was a simple typo.

Comment: @MrThursday: It's always best to use copy-and-paste. You wouldn't believe how often I've seen people spend their precious time answering a question based on what was in the question, only to find out that in fact the OP had introduced that error when retyping their code rather than copying-and-pasting it. A waste of time for all involved. :-) Best,

Comment: @arun15thmay `CheckboxClicked();` needs to set certain controls as (un)available on the page as the checkboxes are used for selection to delete persons. `GetPerson()` Changes another part of the page that displays details of the selected person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#NamesList").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
    CheckboxClicked();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

replaced `return false;` with `e.stopPropagation();`. `return false` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` However, you don't want to prevent the default :)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wpx6A/

Comment: Placement is everything then... for future reference, is it better positioning the stopPropagation at the end of the event? stopImmediatePropagation also works, but yours is a more complete answer. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @MrThursday: It doesn't matter where you put `stopPropagation` provided you do actually execute it; if you always want to execute it, the top of the function is the safest place to put it. The difference here wasn't *placement*, it was that `return false;` != `stopPropagation`. `return false` (in a jQuery event handler) is `stopPropagation` **and** `preventDefault`.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that about return false but makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

this will make sure the event is not propagated.